# JS rmote handler is not working on my android device. and the emulator is handing

Tags: react-native

info Launching Dev Tools...

```
error Google Chrome exited with error:, Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2019:11:35:16 +0000] "GET /launch-js-devtools HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2019:11:35:17 +0000] "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2019:11:35:32 +0000] "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2019:11:35:47 +0000] "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2019:11:36:02 +0000] "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
```

when I am running JS remotely, the error is showed in CMD. and the emulator is hanging.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have marked error listing properly. Good luck!